# Problem with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

I have the following line of the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\Hom(Fz,y)\otimes G(y')
\arrow[r,"\Hom (Fz,\id )\otimes G(f)"]
\arrow[d,"\Hom (Fz,f)\otimes G(\id )"']&
\Hom(Fz,y)\otimes G(y)\dar["\rho_y"] \\
\Hom(Fz,y')\otimes G(y')\rar["\rho_{y'}"]&
d.
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

I expected to have a simple square diagram. However, there are plenty of errors appearing during compilation; I tried to remove some lines of the code and it seems that the problem is in the upper left corner. However, I have got no idea what's wrong.

The exact error info is:

```
! Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.263 \end{tikzcd}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

Comment: Do you have definitions of `\Hom`, `\id`, `\dar` and `\rar` in your preamble? Please make sure that your example has everything it needs to be tested without any modifications, ideally a small, complete example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) . Also, which error, exactly?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Edited, I added the error info and extended it to the "minimal working example".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the options passed to an `\arrow` is a comma separated list, and one of those entries has a comma.

For example, you have

```
\arrow[d,"\Hom (Fz,f)\otimes G(\id )"']
```

which should be

```
\arrow[d,"{\Hom (Fz,f)\otimes G(\id )}"']
```

with the added `{}`, which need to be inside the `""`. This "hides" the comma in the label from the parser parsing the option list.

I also added a `yshift` to one of the labels, to avoid some overlap.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\Hom(Fz,y)\otimes G(y')
\arrow[r,"{\Hom (Fz,\id )\otimes G(f)}"yshift=4pt]
\arrow[d,"{\Hom (Fz,f)\otimes G(\id )}"']
&
\Hom(Fz,y)\otimes G(y)
\dar["\rho_y"] 
\\
\Hom(Fz,y')\otimes G(y')
\rar["\rho_{y'}"]
&
d.
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually, very simple solution - shame on me I haven't thought about it myself.

Answer (score 4):

If an arrow label contains a comma, the label should be braced.

I wouldn't mix `\arrow`, `\rar` and `\dar`. Also you need more room for the top label.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\Hom(Fz,y)\otimes G(y')
  \arrow[r,"{\Hom (Fz,\id )\otimes G(f)}"]
  \arrow[d,"{\Hom (Fz,f)\otimes G(\id )}"']
&[6em]
\Hom(Fz,y)\otimes G(y) \arrow[d,"\rho_y"]
\\
\Hom(Fz,y')\otimes G(y') \arrow[r,"\rho_{y'}"]
&
d.
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]